# Guranteed Delivery of UDP packets

Tags: sockets, udp

I have used UDP protocol for sending packets to the receivers. Can anybody please tell me how can I guarantee that my udp packets are received at the receiver. I can not implement TCP protocol for some reasons. So please suggest that is there any mechanism by which I can guarantee that my packets are received at the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that your packets arrive at the receiver. All you can do is to check with the receiver that your packets have arrived there. And there is no builtin mechanism to do this - you are on your own to implement this.

This can be done for example by letting the receiver send an acknowledgement whenever a packet is received, by periodically asking the receiver which packets were received etc. The best way depends on your actual (and unknown) use case.

Of course this need to be explicitly implemented inside your application protocol and thus inside your applications on both sides of the communication.